# Spring boot resource file not found in server but works in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a file in the resources directory of the spring boot app. I'm able to load it properly in eclipse. But when I build this project and run it on an server it throws `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`.

Whats wrong

I have the below class

```
class TestDataLoader{
@Value("${service.filename}")
private String filename;

@Inject
private FileLoader fileLoader;

public void loadResource(){
List<String> names = fileLoader.loadResource(filename);
}
}
```

This is my FileLoader class

```
public class FileLoader{
public List<String> loadResource(String filename) {
   try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
      // process the data
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }       
}
}
```

My application.yml file looks like below

```
service:
  filename: src/main/Myfile.txt
```

Comment: Do you understand the project structure see in Eclipse is **not** what gets deployed?

Comment: Why don't you put your file under resources and use [ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) instead?

Comment: _"I have a file in the resources directory"_ ... _"service.filename:src/main/Myfile.txt"_... this is also looking in another directory.

Answer (score 1):

**Tip 1**: You should be placing resources in src/main/resources

When you run your server, your file is in the root. You should be okay by doing the chunk below:

```
service:
  filename: Myfile.txt
```

**Tip 2**: You should be using ClassPathResource. see below:

```
public class FileLoader{
  public List<String> loadResource(String filename) {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(filename);
    File file = resource.getFile();
    Path path = file.toPath();
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path)) {
      // process the data
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOGGER.error(e);
    }       
  }
}
```

note: I haven't run the above code...

Comment: Thanks! You made my day. Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(filename);
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
byte[] data = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(inputStream);